# Plugin [id: 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib', version: '0.9.11'] was not found

Tags: jhipster

I've created a Springboot+Angular project using [JHipster Online](https://start.jhipster.tech/#/) and when I'm trying to import this application to eclipse as a gradle project I see below error, which is blocking me to move forward on setting up and running this app. Any advice on this?

**Error:**

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * Where:
      Build file 'C:\GIT_REPO\TestProject\build.gradle' line: 22

 * What went wrong:
      Plugin [id: 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib', version: '0.9.11'] was not found in any of the following sources:

    - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
    - Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib:com.google.cloud.tools.jib.gradle.plugin:0.9.11')
    Searched in the following repositories:
      Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem, but on IntelliJ.
In case someone comes across it: you need to go to Maven settings on IntelliJ and enable plugin registry so that it recognizes JIB.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).